# QGIS Partitioning Regions

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

I have to polygon shapefile maps in QGIS that cover the same area. One with ~90 polygons (call them regions) and the other with about ~800 polygons (call them zones). I want to add a data column in the zone shapefile that indicates what region the zone is located within. Most of the zones fall within a region, but zones fall on region borders. In this case, I'd like the variable to indicate the region that the majority of the zone falls in.

I tried searching around and I couldn't find any guides on how to do this. Any thoughts?